# Quotes created while importing a descripitive csv using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

While importing a CSV with descriptions and #s. Pandas create unwanted inverted commas automatically. How to import a CSV as it is without inverted commas?

Input file as follows,

```
# In this file, you have to specify which information you want to
# extract from the data base.
#
# 6 parts of desired data have to be selected:
#
# 1. cloud or aerosol type
# 2. height profile
# 3. wavelengths
# 4. relative humidity
# 5. max. radius for mass calculations
# 6. optical parameters
#
# All lines which don't start with a "#" have to be filled in.
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
file_path ='/media/input/op.inp'
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep='delimiter'
df.to_csv('out.csv',index=False)
```

Output csv

```
# In this file, you have to specify which information you want to"
# extract from the data base.
#
# 6 parts of desired data have to be selected:
#
# 1. cloud or aerosol type
# 2. height profile
# 3. wavelengths
# 4. relative humidity
# 5. max. radius for mass calculations
# 6. optical parameters
#
"# All lines which don't start with a ""#"" have to be filled in."
```

Unnecessary quotes coming (eg: at the last line) in the output. How to solve this issue?

Comment: try `df = pd.read_csv(file_path)` without `sep='delimiter'`

Comment: @NoobVB It wasn't helping. I could do with the answer I gave below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I could resolve it by saving using the following method.

```
df.to_csv('out.csv',index=False,sep='\t',index=False,sep='\t', doublequote=False,quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='')
```

I used tab instead of space, to make proper spacing.